# If Else Loop PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<tr>';
    if($row['type'] == "product"){
    echo '<td>'.$row['item'].'<br>('.$row['price'].')</td>';
    }else{
    echo '<td>'.$row['item'].'</td>';
    }
    echo '<td>'.$row['type'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';        
}
```

What I want is when `item` `type = product` then the price will show under the item.

Example:

```
Item      |      type  

item1            product
($10.00)

item2            service

item3            product
($20.00)
```

Comment: what is the error you're getting

Comment: Where is error/problem?

Comment: the output only will show all the item with price or all without price...

Comment: Please mention the problem you are facing.

Comment: @Sandeep the output not showing what I want

Comment: Your code is right. Look at your mysql query.

Comment: The reason for that must be in the database contents or the database query. The code seems to be ok. Can you give us more information about the database and your query.

Comment: your code is looks good, post your full code,

Comment: @hherger ya...its my database issue... I solve the problem already...Thank You very much...

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7** mysql_* functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements, it really isn't hard.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    if ($row['type'] == "product") {
        echo '<td>' . $row['item'] . '<br>' . $row['price'] . '</td>';
    } else {
        echo '<td>' . $row['item'] . '</td>';
    }
    echo '<td>' . $row['type'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
  }
```

Comment: Your code contains php errors. Not proper concatenation

Comment: ...which - besides some formatting - is the same as __kc low__'s code.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
echo '<table>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row["item"].'</td><td>'.$row["type"].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    if($row['type'] == "product")
    {
        echo '<tr><td colspan="2">('.$row["price"].')</td></tr>';
    }
}
echo '</table>';
```